# Highlight word or line in Gvim

Tags: vim

I want to mark some words in "Gvim" by color and can't find in "Gvim" manual how to do it.
How can I highlight word/line in "gvim" when I standing on it?

Comment: Do you mean `:set hlsearch` and `<S-*>`?

Comment: No, 
this highlight word that I'm searching.
I want to highlight specific word that i stand on it.
It will be easier to go back to it when I scroll the file.

Comment: "I want to highlight specific word that i stand on it. It will be easier to go back to it when I scroll the file." How about using marks instead: `:help mark`: no need to scroll the file.

Comment: Still prefer to highlight the cell and not mark it

Comment: Recent Vim has a new feature [textprop](https://vimhelp.org/textprop.txt.html) that can do that, but it's a fairly low level API, so it might be quite complex to use it directly... Vim is not really an editor like MS Word or OpenOffice/LibreOffice or Google Docs, where you apply font attributes (bold, italic, underline) to a selection. It's an editor for plain text, and font attributes are typically assigned programmatically by syntax highlighting and pattern matching, so what you're after is a bit odd for Vim to do...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:highlight` and `:match` commands. For e.g., if you want to highlight a word `deadline` then do the following:

```
:highlight DeadlineGroup guifg=#f234f1
:match DeadlineGroup /Deadline/
```

The first command (`:highlight`) will create a highlight-group (`:help highlight-groups`) and the second (`:match`) will map a regex with that highlight-group.

Comment: The highlight works good but the problem is that I want to highlight in a list of numbers.
Since the numbers is random, I want to go over it manually and mark the number in a specific line. means, the number can locate in additional lines but I want to mark only the one I'm standing of it.

Comment: Is there any way to do the same on a specific word I marked in Gvim?